# Is it possible to open application page in sharepoint designer?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, application-pages

I created custom application page using OOB in layouts folder. Is it possible to open this page in SharePoint 2013 designer?

Answer (score 1):

As per me it is not possible to open Application page in SharePoint Designer...

After reading your post I tried doing same and got an alert(attached as image)

[image: While opening application page using SharePoint designer]

You can also refer to this link clearly explaining Ghosting and Unghosting of Pages which says that _layouts and _vti_bin pages are to be excluded from the unghosting part as they cannot be done using sharepoint designer...
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/tools/article.php/c9581/SharePoint-Ghosted-and-Unghosted-Pages.htm

I suppose you got your answer...

Comment: Mark as Answer if you got your query solved otherwise this will still be in the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit application pages in SharePoint Designer.

Because you can put code in them, SharePoint assumes that you had access to the file system but using designer not allowed.

If you want to edit and change any "Layouts"/applicaiton pages, you must edit them with some tool that can put the file on the file system of the web server.

Answer (score 1):

You need Visual Studio to work with application pages.

Answer (score -1):

You can only edit site pages(resides in content DB) using SPD.